# How do I create a popup window with questions?

Tags: c#

So, I have been developing a database of scripts. I have a button, which is named newScript (which when clicked is supposed to ask you the script name and script itself). Since I'm new to the WFP for C#, I'm wondering if anyone could help me out on how to create a popup gui with questions.
Thanks!

Comment: This is where you need to search google. StackOverflow is for questions when you cant find them elsewhere or if you have tried. If you google it and still cant find an answer then post a question here and let us know what you have tried! Thanks! And good luck with your project!

Comment: That's what I've done. Couldn't really find an answer. I know how to create the popup itself, but not on how to add questions. Thanks for the general info btw, I'm new to this site and c#.

Answer (score -1):

I don't program much in c#, but hopefully this helps:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("are all cretans liars?",
    "Question",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll test it out.

Comment: Didn't do much, but thanks for trying to help man. Appreciate it.